# Returning an object type variable in php

Tags: php, object, architecture

Allright, I have 2 classes, one of them, has a variable that is an object type of the other class.
Im finding php being a pain regarding object variables, or maybe Im not doing it right.

Example:

```
class Class1
{
    private $Name;
    private $Class2 ---> Cant do!: private Class2 $Class2;

     public function __construct($aClass2, $aName) 
     {
       $this->Class2 = new Class2($aClass2->getName());
       $this->$Name = $aName
     }

     function getName() {
       return $this->Name;
     }

     function getClass2() {
       return $this->Class2;
    }
}

class Class2
{
   private $Name;

     public function __construct($aName) 
     {
       $this->Name = $aName;
     }

     function getName() {
       return $this->Name;
     }

}


$aClass1->getClass2()->properties?????
```

It seems that I can't have the variable Class2 of class1 as a Class2 object in Its Firm.

Thing is, whenever I call the function getClass2 in an instance of a class1 object, the compiler does not seem to understand that Im returning a Class2 object, so I can't dive in the properties of the Class2 object.

How do I solve this, or what is the best option to overdo this? 
I did a lot of research on php manuals but it does not seem to truly cover this part, and if it does, Im really not getting the idea.

Im using NetBeans by the way.

Thank you in advance and for any time I may rob you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not possible as PHP is loosely typed. You can add javadoc like annotations to enable code completion in IDEs:

```
/**
 *
 * @var Class2
 */
private $Class2
```

Comment: This solution works well with [Eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) in most cases.

Comment: Man!, thank you!
I realized I should have picked java instead of php for web developing. :(